# Why don't consecutive setTimeouts run independently and update the UI after the callback completes on mobile?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

CodePen: https://codepen.io/adamzerner/pen/pLQmXr?editors=1010#0

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $button = $('button');

  $button.on('click', function () {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 25000; i++) {
      setTimeout(createCb($button, i), 0);
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
      $button.text('Simulate');
    }, 0);
  });
});

function createCb($button, i) {
  return function () {
    $button.text((i / 250).toFixed(0) + '%');
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Simulate</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My goal is for the simulate button to have its text change to say "x%" as the simulation is running. Without using `setTimeout`, the UI won't update until after the simulation finishes.

Using `setTimeout` to update the UI works on my laptop on Chrome. It also works when using the mobile emulator in the dev tools. But when I actually go to the URL on mobile, it *doesn't* work. Why is that, and what can be done to get it to work?

Note: Using `100` for the `setTimeout` delay rather than `0` doesn't help - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/adamzerner/pen/qoQzZw?editors=1010#0).

Comment: Most likely because your `setTimeout` use `0` as delay value. The minimum refresh time is from 4 ms, but I would use 10 ms to be safe cross browsers.

Comment: @LGSon: The 4ms thing was only true briefly, a few years ago. The true story [is much more complicated](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#timer-initialisation-steps). 0 is allowed for a non-nested timeout.

Comment: @LGSon Using `100` as the delay value doesn't work either ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/adamzerner/pen/qoQzZw?editors=1010#0)).

Comment: What is the simulation? Does it run on the main UI thread? If not, where/how does it run?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder And will using `0` for the dealy work 100% cross browsers?

Comment: @LGSon: Why ask me? You can easily check. Last time I checked (months if not years ago), most did the callback as soon as possible (no artificial 4ms delay), Firefox didn't. The point is: There's nothing wrong with using 0 to mean "as soon as possible" (of course, in modern browsers, you can use promise resolution for something sooner than a 0ms timer.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, the simulation runs on the main UI thread. Eg. it's running in the JavaScript runtime rather than on a server, and it's not using a web worker or anything.

Comment: @AdamZerner: I don't think we can answer this without the simulation code (or more accurately, a [mcve] of the simulation). If the simulation never yielded, nothing would ever get updated, even on desktop, so presumably it's...complicated.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I asked you as I assumed when someone state something, like `0 is allowed for a non-nested timeout.`, I expect them to know.

Comment: @LGSon: If you're asking "does passing 0 work 100% cross-browser", the answer is: Of course it does, and schedules that platform's earliest `setTimeout`-based callback, otherwise a huge amount of code both you and I have seen would fail. If you're asking "do browsers actually do a 0ms callback" my answer is above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you for your clarification about that. Will be more specific next time :)

Comment: @LGSon: It wasn't necessarily at your end, could easily have been me misreading the question. :-)

Comment: Filling the event loop with 2500 events seems like the wrong approach.

Comment: Works fine on chrome mobile on android.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The simulation code in my actual app is large and complicated. I left that part out of the question because it seemed distracting and irrelevant, given that the issue is present even without any simulation code (eg. the CodePen example). Are you saying that even if a solution is presented for the CodePen example, it is likely to not work when that solution is attempted with real simulation code?

Comment: @AdamZerner: The CodePen link in the question runs fine (animating the %) for me on my Xperia mobile (using Chrome). But doesn't seem to work on Chrome on iOS (on my iPad).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Huh. It seems that it depends on things like the device and browser then. In which case, do you think I should close the question (because a comprehensive answer addressing each device and browser would be impractical)?

Comment: @AdamZerner: This could be one of those awkward times when we won't know whether to close the question until we know the answer to it. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah, that makes sense :) I suppose it doesn't hurt to have it open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two aspects to this answer: What's going wrong in the example, and what I'd suggest doing instead of using `setTimeout`.

#### What's going wrong

The problem is that you're scheduling all the updates to happen at the same time. On some browsers (Chrome on desktop or [for me] on Android, for instance), you see the process occur; on others, although it does occur, it it's visible (Chrome on iOS, for me).

You've said the simulation code runs on the main UI thread (not on a web worker or similar). Since it will be competing with this update process, any solution to showing this progress is going to depend greatly on the interplay with your simulation code. Clearly, if you're seeing any updates at all in the browser UI, the simulation code must be yielding back to the browser (otherwise all updates would be blocked entirely until it completed).

But for instance, using `i` as the timeout makes it work without the simulation code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $button = $('button');

  $button.on('click', function () {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 25000; i++) {
      setTimeout(createCb($button, i), i); // *** Here
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
      $button.text('Simulate');
    }, i); // *** And here
  });
});

function createCb($button, i) {
  return function () {
    $button.text((i / 250).toFixed(0) + '%');
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Simulate</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Obviously that specific example will take 25 seconds to complete; you an adjust that by doing some math on `i`. For instance, for 12.5 seconds instead, just divide by 2:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $button = $('button');

  $button.on('click', function () {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 25000; i++) {
      setTimeout(createCb($button, i), i / 2); // *** Here
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
      $button.text('Simulate');
    }, i / 2); // *** And here
  });
});

function createCb($button, i) {
  return function () {
    $button.text((i / 250).toFixed(0) + '%');
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Simulate</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But again, that's just this synthetic example.

#### What I'd suggest instead

I'd suggest moving the simulation to a web worker. They're [extremely well-supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=worker), and that would prevent the simulation from blocking UI updates. Have the simulation post a message with progress to the main UI thread, and have the main UI thread show that message, like this:

**Note**: [Here it is on plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/XIKxpV6oWyWiwklFBSLh/), the snippet below doesn't work on iOS Chrome for me, but the concept **does**. I think it's the workaround I had to use because snippets don't support a separate file for the worker.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $button = $('button');

  // The worker code. The Blob/createObjectURL stuff is just because
  // Stack Snippets don't support having a separate file for the worker.
  // Your real code would be just: var worker = new Worker("your-worker-file.js");
  var worker = new Worker(
    URL.createObjectURL(
      new Blob(
        [$("#worker-code").text()],
        {type: 'application/javascript'}
      )
    )
  );
  worker.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
    if (e.data) {
      switch (e.data.cmd) {
        case "progress":
          $button.text((e.data.value / 250).toFixed(0) + "%");
          break;
        case "complete":
          $button.text("Simulate");
          break;
      }
    }
  });
  $button.on("click", function() {
    worker.postMessage("start");
  });
});
```

```html
<button>Simulate</button>

<script id="worker-code" type="something-browser-will-not-run">
this.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
  if (e.data === "start") {
    // To make progress visible, had to use a large number (10000x your original)
    for (var n = 0; n < 250000000; ++n) {
      if (n % 10000 === 1) {
        this.postMessage({cmd: "progress", value: n / 10000});
      }
    }
    this.postMessage({cmd: "complete"});
  }
});
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: **"Clearly, if you're seeing any updates at all in the browser UI, the simulation code must be yielding back to the browser (otherwise all updates would be blocked entirely until it completed)."** Correct. I have it set up such that it does yield back to the browser before all 25,000 simulations have finished. As of the time of me posting this question, I accomplished that by putting each individual simulation inside of a `setTimeout` (eg. such that there are 25,000 `setTimeouts`).

Comment: **"Obviously that specific example will take 25 seconds to complete"** I would think so too, but that isn't happening at all when I run the code snippet. It's taking about 10 seconds or so. Is it taking 25 seconds for you? If not, I am very confused as to why. I would think that after `i` milliseconds, the callback is put on the queue, and that the event loop pushes the stuff in the queue onto the call stack to be executed once the call stack clears. And so it should be taking _at least_ 25 seconds, because it takes at least 25 seconds for the last callback to be put on the queue.

Comment: **"The problem is that you're scheduling all the updates to happen at the same time."** I don't understand what you mean by that. My understanding is that the `setTimeout`s are saying, "put this callback on the queue immediately (without a delay)". And so after the click event listener callback finishes running, the queue will have a list of callbacks to execute, and that they will be executed in order, not at the same time, and that the UI will update every time the call stack is emptied. So the timing would go: push from queue to stack, execute the one frame on the stack, update UI, repeat.

Comment: **"I'd suggest moving the simulation to a web worker."** That seems like a great idea. However, when I run your web worker snippet, both here and on Plunker, it updates the UI in a "jagged" manner. Eg. the button will go from 3 to 8 to 20 to 46 to "Simulate", rather than 1, 2, 3 etc. in a smooth manner.

Comment: In my actual app I tried the web worker approach and it did work! It was smooth, not jaggedy. I'm still interested in hearing your responses to my follow up questions though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pseudorecursively set the timeouts, e.g.:

```
  function animatePercentage($button, max = 100, curr = 0) {
     $button.text((curr / max).toFixed(0) + '%');
     if(curr /  max < 100) setTimeout(animatePercentage, 0, $button, max, curr + 1);
  }
```

So then you can do:

```
  $button.on('click', function () {
    animatePercentage($button, 25);
  });
```

without filling (or exceeding) the event queue and without creating 2500 closures, which might be not that memory wise.

Comment: That code you posted doesn't seem to work ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/adamzerner/pen/pLQMyG?editors=1010#0)). However, the idea to not actually create a `setTimeout` for each simulation is great! I'm fine with only have 100. But even with that approach ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/adamzerner/pen/RMqXRZ?editors=1010)), it seems to have the same problem of working on desktop but not mobile (at least on iPhone + Chrome) :/

Comment: @adam https://codepen.io/adamzerner/pen/pLQMyG?editors=1010#0 yes i had a small mistake in it :)